# How to read app.json programmatically from node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, node-modules

I'm writing a module that I'll be using npm to install in the future. I need to be able to read app.json to get configuration information. I would like to reference app.json using an absolute path, but:

```
import app from 'AppName/app.json'
```

doesn't work because my module won't know the name of the app in the future. How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be absolute? Or is relative okay?

Comment: Why do you need to reference app.json using an absolute path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference it using a relative path.

Using import won't work, unless you are using ES6, as you are not exporting anything in the app.json so you will have to use require instead.  If the file that is requiring it is located in  `node_modules/your_module_name/` something like this should find the `app.json`

`const app = require('../../app.json')`

or if using ES6

`import app from '../../app.json'`

Comment: i was hoping for an absolute path to the root directory but i guess it's safe to assume that app.json will be in the same directory as node_modules. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can reference using a relative path.

For example:

```
import app from '../app.json'
```

or

```
import app from './app.json'
```